# How to reverse Xamarin update?

Tags: macos, xamarin, monogame

The latest Xamarin update for mac has several severe issues. The mac 'apple' menu is duplicated, and the monogame plugin is not recognized anymore. To me, this makes Xamarin unusable. How can I uninstall the latest update?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MonoGame Addin is failing, but I know it works in the latest release as I am using it...

- Xamarin Studio Version 5.10.1 (build 6)
- MonoGame Addin 3.4.0.455

Try this:

- Close Xamarin Studio
- Delete the local MonoGame Addin directory
  .

> ${HOME}/Library/Application Support/XamarinStudio-5.0/LocalInstall/Addins/MonoDevelop.MonoGame.3.4.0.455

- Restart Xamarin Studio
- Reinstalled the MonoGame Addin

[image]

- Open Addin Manager to confirm

[image]

If it still fails with the same error message, it is another of your locally installed Addins that is loading before MonoGame that is causing the cyclic failure. Remove them one by one (or all) to test which one is the cause.